# Transferencia de archivos incorrecta en Java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando realizar una transferencia de archivos de un programa escrito en Java a otro. Después de pelear un rato ya he conseguido conectar ambas aplicaciones, pero me topo con que las transferencias no se hacen correctamente, se **comen bytes**, es decir que si el archivo original tiene 3MB el servidor lee y almacena 2.7MB, por ejemplo.

El código del lado del servidor es un poco más elaborado, puesto que es un hilo que se crea de otro etc.

```
public class CmdThread extends Thread {

private final Socket SO;
private final BufferedReader entrada;
private final BufferedOutputStream salida;
private String peticion, cmd, nombreArchivo;
private Long tam;

public CmdThread(Socket SO) throws IOException {
    this.SO = SO;
    if (this.SO != null) {
        entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.SO.getInputStream()));
        salida = new BufferedOutputStream(this.SO.getOutputStream());
    } else {
        entrada = null;
        salida = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        peticion = entrada.readLine();
        System.out.println("Peticion: " + peticion);
        String[] str = peticion.split("&");
        System.out.println("Paramns: " + Arrays.toString(str));
        cmd = str[0];
        nombreArchivo = str[1];
        tam = Long.valueOf(str[2]);
        BufferedOutputStream salidaDisco = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(nombreArchivo)));
        while (entrada.ready()) {
            salidaDisco.write(entrada.read());
        }
        salida.flush();
        salida.close();
        salidaDisco.flush();
        salidaDisco.close();
        entrada.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CmdThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}}
```

En la parte del cliente tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class ArchivosCliente {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFileChooser selector = new JFileChooser();
    selector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int res = selector.showOpenDialog(selector);
    if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File fila = selector.getSelectedFile();
        String comando = "UP";
        String del = "&";
        String nombreArchivo = fila.getName();
        String remoto = "127.0.0.1";
        int puerto = 57000;
        String tam = String.valueOf(fila.length());
        Socket so = new Socket(remoto, puerto);
        so.setSoLinger(true, 5);
        BufferedOutputStream salida = new BufferedOutputStream(so.getOutputStream());
        BufferedInputStream entrada = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fila));
        System.out.println("Peticion: " + comando + del + nombreArchivo + del + tam + "\n");
        salida.write((comando + del + nombreArchivo + del + tam + "\n").getBytes());
        int n;
        while ((n = entrada.read()) != -1) {
            salida.write(n);
        }
        salida.flush();
        salida.close();
        entrada.close();
    }
}}
```

Después de pelearme con los BrokenPipe y los Reset, esto ya no lo entiendo.

Comment: Una pregunta, tienes implementado algún mecanismo de 'handshake' o algún protocolo que establezca parámetros de `STX` y `ETX`?

Comment: nono, lo que he expuesto en el post es lo que tengo. Estoy como quien dice empezando con la programación. Por el momento son cosas muy sencillas

Comment: ¿Por qué no intentas remplazar tu try por un try con recursos?

Comment: No veo cómo puede eso arreglar el problema, pero igualmente lo he probado. El resultado es el mismo. Siguen faltando bytes. Gracias.